# WP Site hacked , Page Keep Coming back when site visited

Tags: php, wordpress

I really need help. One of my wordpress site got hacked and i can't find the hacked files. The page keep coming back by reinserting the post. Lets say i manually delete the post from the db, the post will reinsert as another ID when the site is visited.

And also if i have already login as admin, the page would hide itself.

The page address
http://urbanyoga.com.sg/3gp-sexy-videos/

Any advice would be appreciated. I have installed both sucuri and wordfence but nothing detected.

Comment: I'd suggesting tearing it all down, fresh install. Copy your theme and fine comb any files in that, but delete every other file (including plugins) and do a fresh install. This include .htaccess files. Edit: as pointed out below, assuming backups don't exist. Use those if they do.

Comment: Ask your hosting company for the website backup....

Comment: Lookup your WP version and search for common exploits for that version. Odds are you'll find it pretty soon.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answers, In the end i do a fresh installation and imported the posts and media data

Answer (score 0):

In the top of your theme files there is a code strip before the real code starts. It creates the redirect. 
Remove it manually by editing the .php-files and the .htacess. Otherwise you can try a plugin called "Wordfence Security"